# How do I setup Weblogic as one of my Servers in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, weblogic

I downloaded the Weblogic .zip file from the oracle's server but when I am trying to add the server to my Netbeans it gives an error that says "The entered installation directory is not properly structured."

I have also attached a screenshot to show it, can you please help me with the issue. I tried to find a solution online but there is nothing that actually solves my problem. For e.g someone said to update the IDE, so that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: What is the full path that you have in that screenshot? Are you sure you're giving it the domains folder and not the folder above it? The instructions on here seem pretty terrible... they have a folder for the server outside the domain... http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/wls_12c_netbeans_install/wls_12c_netbeans_install.html?cid=6396&ssid=3984560036031

Comment: I went through the instructions and didnt even know that we were supposed to create a dir called domain and then point the variable at that folder, the instructions in the link are really terrible. Thanks for the help though, Ill give it a try later on. Upvoted.

Comment: did you achieve something?

Comment: @kiduxa Yeah I could make it work on Ubuntu, but on CentOS it worked completely fine. Still could not figure out why it didnt work on Ubuntu though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem permission: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2582875
Just make sure that the user that is running netbeans has the same permissions on weblogic directory.

Comment: Yes I gave full access to that folder to all Users and also repeated the whole process as a root user as well. But to no use.

Comment: I had the same problem recently. I started ubuntu as myUsername. With this user a create other user called 'oracle' with 'oInstall' group. When I call netbeans I was using myUsername so I got the same error that you had. What I did was assign to myUsername the group oInstall and I gave 775 permission to the directory where I installed weblogic. Then I tried to run netbeans again using myUsername and it worked. There must be something with the permissions that you didnt do well.

Comment: Run this command in console id -a with the user that must install oracle products in your machine and do ls -l in the directory where you installed weblogic. Let me know.

Comment: I uninstalled Ubuntu next day after I posted this question because Weblogic installation was kind of urgent. But if it worked for you I am sure it does, marked it as answer, should help someone else who comes across same issue.

Comment: did you solve this problem?, i have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing here, but you probably unpack the zip file but didn't run "configure.sh" to finish the WebLogic configuration.

Run `./configure.sh` inside of your WebLogic folder and then try it again.

Answer (score 1):

- in netbeans for "Server Location" you should put MW_HOME\wlserver_10.3
  presuming that you use "Domain Registration Type" Local Domain
- then click Next, and netbeans will detect in Instance Properties 
  Domain like MW_HOME\user_projects\domains\sw_domain
  just enter Username/Password and click Finish

Answer (score 0):

The server location is:
*/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/user_projects/domains/base_domain